# HTML text input breaks positioning on Iphone 6/7 plus

Tags: javascript, html, ios

I try to find some workarounds for mobile safari bug:

For example I have a clear html page with

1. Viewport settings width=device-width, noscalable
2. Body with position:fixed
3. Two HTMLInputs created by js and placed to center of screen

All works fine on ever devices but on Iphones 6 plus and 7 plus we have a great problem:

If I've focus input and then hide keyboard, all window positioning become diverged from rendered position. Input could be only focused if I've click ~100px higher of it visible position. Moreover, each additional elements on page (even canvas with webgl content) also will get wrong coordinates on each tap/touchstart and so on.

I've connect iphone for debug, and I can see that browser thinks that input placed not where it rendered. Also i can vertically scroll page with finger, and real rendered inputs will stay in place, but area from browser will moves up and down right up to his rendered position.
[image]

Bug could be reproduced only if few tabs opened in browser in landscape orientation (i'll highlight tabs red on screenshot).

Can't reproduced on iphones5-6, because there is no tabs, but also can't be reproduced on ipad, which has the same tabs.

Example is here: http://baker-feather-16713.bitballoon.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is the fact that safari allow user to scroll page to fullscreen ever if you set html/body width and height to 100%. So, when keyboard showed content scrolls up despite that body has position "fixed" and it rendered with bug when keyboard becomes hidden.

Solution is very simple: just need to do scrollTo(0, 0) when keyboard hidden, e.g.:

```
document.addEventListener('focusout', function(e) { window.scrollTo(0, 0) });
```